# type cast exponential number to int or float

Tags: php, casting

The following code:

```
echo (int) "2e2";
echo (int) 2e2;
echo (float) "2e2";
```

outputs

```
2
200
200
```

.. and i have no idea why. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"2e2" is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), meaning 2*10<sup>2</sup> == 200.

1. In your first example, parsing the string as an int reads only digits up to the first non-digit (so it ignores the `e`).
2. The PHP parser treats `2e2` as a [float literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) with value 200.0 and this gives 200 when cast to a int.
3. Parsing the string as a float understands the notation and gives the expected result of 200.